# Which one of the Block Cipher modes is the best?

Tags: block-cipher, modes-of-operation, tls, cbc, ctr

I have two questions regarding the Block Cipher Modes:

1. Which one of the modes is considered the best?
   I know CBC has a problem of IV since the next block of the plain text is XORed with the result of cipher text of the last block and the same with OFB. Is CTR the best one or not?
2. In "SSL with blockciphers in CBC-mode", does TLS 1.2 use CBC or is there any other modes that is used with TLS 1.2 (SSL 3.0)?

Comment: see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/225/132 for modes of encryption

Comment: See also http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf

Comment: There is no "best".  Best for what purpose?  They have different characteristics.  Those characteristics are well-documented.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I like the modes that support integrity checking and authentication, e.g. GCM, as they only require one key, and are not vulnerable to changes in the cipher text. One particular important problem area is padding oracle attacks, which are much more common than people seem to admit.

Note that GCM/AES is - just like CTR - a block cipher in stream cipher mode; Basically GCM consists of a GMAC and CTR combination.

GCM is supported by XML encryption v1.1 (XML encryption by itself is *very* vulnerable to padding oracle attacks). There is also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288 which describes the use in TLS and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5084 which describes the use in CMS.

GCM seems to have some support, e.g. Java 8 introduces GCM in the standard Java Runtime. For Java 7 and below it is required to use an external provider such as Bouncy Castle.

Comment: GCM is not really usable in Java 7 because actual cipher-suites are not present in that JCE. Most people use IAIK or BouncyCastle for that purpose. Java 8 should also have GCM by default.

Comment: @kravietz Tested against Java 7 update 60 and - although I thought it was backported - didn't find GCM. Thanks, updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it's quite misleading - I have done exactly the same a while ago. When you see implementation of GCM params you expect the GCM is there too, but then I get these NoSuchAlgorithmExceptions...

Answer (score 6):

There is no "best" mode of operation, just modes more or less useful in different situations.

CBC-mode requires an initialization vector which is unpredictable by the adversary (preferably random), especially if this adversary can mount a chosen plaintext attack. Up to TLS 1.0 (i.e. also in SSL 2.0 and 3.0), CBC was used with a "use last block of previous message as IV", and this is obviously not unpredictable if there is some time between the messages. TLS 1.1 fixes this by using a random per-message IV.

This problem can be avoided by implementations (without violating the protocol) by sending an empty message (which still gets padded to at least a full block) directly before any real message (i.e. after the application decided the content of the real message), and this is what OpenSSL does for quite some time. (It helps only on the sending side, not the receiving one, though.)

CTR mode requires that the initialization vector is non-repeating for all uses of the same key, as identical IVs give an identical key stream (which is then XORed with the message) - the same is valid for OFB mode.

Comment: Is there a link to the security analysis that lead to the decision to let OpenSSL send empty messages the way you describe? The security of CBC does not require the IV to be "unpredictable" but only that it is generated in such way that its distribution is uniform. Then again, there are adaptive timing attacks that can exploit the AtE scheme of SSL 3/TLS 1 in case of IV collisions, but such attacks would still be possible unless the other peer actually verifies that every other message is empty.

Comment: What I understood about CTR is that the IV is a combination of nonce and counter; the nonce does not change every time but the counter increases every time, so that means the IV is not identical and it is changed with other blocks. But the real question is why don't they use CTR with SSL? What I think is that CTR is better than CBC in terms of the attack against IV

Comment: @HenrickHellström: Actually, there are known attacks against CBC with predictable (but well distributed) IVs. The recently published "Beast" attack on SSL/TLS 1.0 is such an example.  The empty message that OpenSSL sends disrupts this attack because the IV used to encrypt the real message (record) is the last ciphertext block of the empty record, and that cannot be predicted.

Comment: @poncho: Thanks for the reference. BEAST is a chosen plain text attack, which means it is a concern for e.g. browsers and other software where the attacker might get to choose the plain text without first compromising the whole system. For better or worse, in most other cases (such as C/S business software without scripting capabilities) an attacker who is able to choose the plain text would imply an even worse security breach.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann The SSL vulnerability you describe is present in TLS 1.0 and lower, not only in SSL 3.0.

Comment: OCB is now [more liberally licensed](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/license.htm), would that make it a strong contender in your opinion, Paŭlo?

Comment: @owlstead I still see "free in Open source", "free for non-military non-commercial (or research) purposes". I don't know if there are yet suitable open source implementations for commercial use. Other than that, having an easily usable AEAD mode is good.

Comment: Any software implementation should now be free if not used for military purposes, and if it includes the license (check the date and item III of the last paragraph of the second license). You may notice that the date of the license has changed too.

Comment: Ah, I read the summary paragraph about the second license wrong (different grouping).

Answer (score 2):

I think the attack on CBC that you're referring to is a known-plaintext attack where an attacker can manipulate a plaintext by adjusting the previous block of ciphertext. But this same sort of attack also applies to CTR.

[edit] I misinterpreted the OP's referenced to a CBC attack. The one I describe here allows intelligently modifying plaintext by modifying the ciphertext. This is a valid attack to be concerned about and applies to both CBC and CTR, so I will leave it as a part of the analysis of the modes of operation, but it is *not* the attack mentioned by the OP. [/edit]

CTR is a good mode overall, but it must be used in the right context given that it is a stream cipher. You should not use it in a case where you will be re-encrypting the same data with the same key and IV (for example if you're doing disk encryption). In practice, this often means that you should only use it if you're willing to completely re-encrypt data every time it's edited/saved/transmitted.

The newer block mode XTS is an interesting mode because it does away with the ability to modify the plaintext by altering the ciphertext (like mentioned above), and it also allows for single-block encrypt/decrypt access like ECB and CTR. The disadvantage to it is that it has the same information leakage that ECB and CTR have, namely editing/re-saving ciphertext leaks exactly which blocks were modified. In practice, however, I don't think many people are concerned by that.

Right now there is no official "best" mode, but it seems like there is a heavy favoring of XTS due to the fact that plaintext is not malleable and that it is well-suited for many uses, both of CBC's and CTR's domains. Disk encryption products have switched en masse to XTS recently. I don't think network communications has, though.

For what it's worth, in the book *Practical Cryptography* (first edition) by Niels Ferguson and Bruce Schneier they made a comment that CTR was "their personal favorite" (paraphrased quote) mode of operation at the time. That was written in about '03, though, and I don't know if that comment was preserved for the second edition of the book; it  was made long before XTS came around.

Comment: Could you elaborate how one would apply these CBC attacks to CTR?

Comment: The confusion was on my part about which CBC attack the OP referenced. I thought it was the attack where an attack can XOR against ciphertext[n-1] to modify plaintext[n], but I was mistaken. Your comment prompted me to re-read the OP, and I've edited my post for clarification. To be clear, it is the attack of XORing against the ciphertext to intelligently modify the plaintext that I was referring to, and that type of attack applies to both CBC and CTR without a MAC.

Comment: Ah, yes. CTR is even more malleable than CBC (since changing arbitrary ciphertext bits in CTR change the corresponding plaintext bits, and nothing else, while in CBC you'll also get a "random" block as the result, if you are not just attacking the first block by changing the IV).