# Should I use hash of passphrase as AES256 key

Tags: hash, aes, key-derivation, sha-256

As title I have a password-like passphrase (8 chars at least) that is then hashed with argon2(with the salt is SHA256 of that passphrase).

Then use it as AES256 key along with a random IV generated by CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(256 / 8);

Is it okay?

Or should I use the IV as a key?

Comment: Did you search our site? We had tons of questions like this. Hash functions cannot increase the entropy. So, your input has 64-bit entropy ( assuming the ASCII encoding). This is a matter of time for huge adversaries like NSA, Summit, and collective bitcoin miners to reach your key in seconds. IV is not a key. Start searching from here [password+AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=password+AES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with the salt is SHA256 of that passphrase

Don't use the SHA-256 of the passphrase as the salt; randomly generate it so it's not the same for identical passwords.

> CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(256 / 8);

Don't use CryptoJS. From memory, it generated random numbers incorrectly, the passphrase methods for the ciphers used/use some broken KDF, and it doesn't offer AEAD modes.

See if you can use [libsodium.js](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js) instead. Alternatively, there's the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API). Unfortunately, I know nothing about JavaScript.

> Then use it as AES256 key

I presume you're currently using AES-CBC (the default for CryptoJS). It needs to be paired with HMAC-SHA-256 or HMAC-SHA-512 to be secure.

If you switch to a better library, you should just use an AEAD mode like AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305. You then don't need to apply HMAC because they authenticate the inputs for you. Importantly, with most AEAD modes, you should use a counter nonce (number used once), meaning you increment it after each encryption operation with the same key.

> should I use the IV as a key?

No, the IV should only be used as the IV and is a different size to the key. The Argon2 output should be used as the key.

> along with a random IV

With AES-CBC, the IV should indeed be random and unpredictable for each encryption operation. It should not be reused with the same key. You can prepend it to the ciphertext output.

Comment: CBC requires not only random also [unpredictable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/why-is-cbc-with-predictable-iv-considered-insecure-against-chosen-plaintext-atta) in network communications.

Comment: I originally wrote that but dumbed it down because random via a CSPRNG is unpredictable. I will add it back.

Comment: I'm not sure a counter nonce is a good suggestion. In many cases there is no good way to keep the state of the counter. And e.g. AES-GCM leaks the key if you accidentally re-use that nonce.

Comment: @Elias It's not sensible to use a random 96-bit nonce either unless you're rotating the key frequently.

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to point out the danger. For a counter it's not being able to keep the state properly for random nonces it's not having good randomness or too few bits.